# Pattern-matching with (higher-order) functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm trying to learn a bit of Haskell with the online book "Learn you a Haskell" and I have a question about higher-order functions.

I saw [some examples](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) and I want to do a few more advanced functions but I don't know why I always read the following exception:

> *** Exception: euler13.hs:(11,0)-(15,39):
>   Non-exhaustive patterns in function apply

And the function I defined is this one:

```
apply :: (Num b, Ord b) => (a -> a) -> b -> [a] -> [a]
apply f n [] = []
apply f n [x]
    | n <= 1    = map f [x]
    | otherwise = apply f (n-1) (map f [x])
```

I want to apply 'n' times a concrete function called 'f' to a list '[x]'. I tried to make this function polymorphic so the type of the param is 'a'. But I want to use numbers and lists also,  so directly I'm using a list (if I want to use the function just for a number,  it would be [number] obviously)

Could anybody help me please?  I love this language but it's a bit difficult when you are learning because it's so different of Java or c (for example)

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest renaming the title of the question: this is an issue with Pattern Matching, not necessarily with higher-order functions.

Comment: Ok it's done. Is it right now? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `[]` around the `x`. Otherwise the 2nd pattern can only match lists with 1 element only.

```
apply f n x
    | n <= 1    = map f x
    | otherwise = apply f (n-1) (map f x)
```

Comment: And while we're at it: Rename it to `xs`, the more common name for "a list of anything".

Comment: yeah it's true. The problem is I was trying a lot of things doing changes and more changes and nothing. But the correct is to use 'xs'

Answer (score 11):

This is no different from what others have said, but maybe the point should be labored? There are two basic 'constructors' for lists, and thus two basic cases you need to consider in defining functions from lists: arguments of the form  `[]` and `(:)`. the latter, `(:)` can join anything with a list of that kind of thing, thus `1` with `[]`  -- `1:[]` or `[1]`. Or it can join `1` with something of just that kind: `1:(1:[])` i.e. `1:[1]`, i.e. `[1,1]` as the special syntax lets us write.

It would be more obvious what would had gone wrong if you had defined lists yourself, writing:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

The use of `[]` and `x:xs` is just swank sugar for something like this.  Similarly, the special `String` sugar lets us write `"abc"` rather than `['a','b','c']`, which is way better than `'a':'b':'c':[]`.  (With the above definition we would have to write `Cons 'a' (Cons 'b' (Cons 'c' Nil)))` which is a bit much for a short string! -- though it also brings out why one should prefer `ByteString` and `Text` representations of strings for many purposes.)  With a more verbose list definition like this, we need to add our own `map` (or rather `fmap`), so we can say

```
instance Functor List where 
   fmap f Nil = Nil
   fmap f (Cons first rest) = Cons (f first) (fmap f rest)
```

Notice that in defining `fmap` for this case I had to consider both types of constructor for my List type, `Nil` and `Cons first rest` (or `Cons x xs` as it is often written).

Or maybe you haven't got up to the general discussion of the `Functor` type class in LYAH -- in that case, just consider that you can define your own `map` as

```
listMap f Nil = Nil
listMap f (Cons first rest) = Cons (f first) (listMap f rest)
```

In any case, given this desugared rewrite of the list type, your actual function definition would be:

```
apply :: (Num b, Ord b) => (a -> a) -> b -> List a -> List a
apply f n Nil = Nil
apply f n (Cons first Nil)
    | n <= 1    = fmap f (Cons first Nil)  -- or listMap f (Cons first Nil)
    | otherwise = apply f (n-1) (fmap f (Cons first Nil))
```

The cases you have covered are:

```
apply f n Nil 
apply f n (Cons first Nil)
```

`Cons first Nil` is the same as `first : []` or `[first]` -- i.e. `[x]` as you write it. But this means you haven't covered every case, your definition is 'non-exhaustive'. You haven't said how to apply `f` and `n` to a list if it has more than one member. What if a list has the form `Cons x (Cons y Nil)` or `Cons x (Cons y (Cons z Nil))` rather than `Nil` (your first line) or `Cons x Nil` (your second line)?

The solution is as others said, or using our desugared list-type:

```
apply :: (Num b, Ord b) => (a -> a) -> b -> List a -> List a
apply f n Nil = Nil
apply f n (Cons first rest)
    | n <= 1    = fmap f (Cons first rest)
    | otherwise = apply f (n-1) (fmap f (Cons first rest))
```

Here the 'variable' `rest` covers all lists, `Nil` or not. Thus we get:

```
*Main> apply (+1) 3 Nil
Nil
*Main> apply (+1) 3 (Cons 3 Nil)
Cons 6 Nil
```

as you would, but also:

```
*Main> apply (+1) 3 (Cons 0 (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)))
Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 5 Nil))
```

Comment: Truly impressive all the answer. Thanks for explained me. Yes I haven't got up this part in LYAH. The only thing I didn't understand is why you defined your own "map" function and why did you use Nil and Cons rather than [] and : ? I think the sytantic sugar is easier to use. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

You define `apply` for two cases: n and an empty list and n and a list of one element. What happens when the list contains more than one element? That's the missing pattern.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a new answer, compared to the others given, but hopefully is insightful nonetheless.

You have already demonstrated some understanding of pattern matching in function definitions; when the first pattern fails to match, evaluation moves on to the next. Patterns that are able to fail to match are considered "refutable".

Generally it is a good idea to have your last function definition be "irrefutable", meaning it always matches. From the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17):

> The irrefutable patterns are as follows: a variable, a wildcard, N apat where N is a constructor defined by newtype and apat is irrefutable, var@apat where apat is irrefutable, or of the form ~apat. All other patterns are refutable.

Your misunderstanding was that you thought `[x]` is a variable (irrefutable pattern), when it is in fact a refutable pattern (the pattern for a single-element list, which binds `x` to that single element).

Suppose you wrote a function that works only on lists of length 3. If you want a more descriptive error message than "non-exhaustive patterns", then you can use the wildcard (underscore) irrefutable pattern. A trivial example:

```
sum3 [x,y,z] = x+y+z
sum3 _       = error "sum3 only works on lists of length 3"
```

Comment: Oh It's good to know it. Actually I am learning this language on my free time, not at the university so I still don't know pretty much about Haskell but it's good to learn some techniques and "hacks" like the above one.